# My mom's MacBook Air is making rattling noises when it is moved ever since I dropped it. Diagnosis?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

It dropped like two or three feet. The noise is like a rattling of a beanbag, but I don't know the source.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of sounding obvious, something inside broke. If you are the handy type and have the tools you could open it up following the directions for your model on iFixit.com or take it to an Apple store (or other Apple dealer who does repairs) and see what they say.

Also do not power on a laptop with something rattling around in it after you dropped it. It could make the problem worse.

Comment: Well, that is a major problem.

Comment: If the battery snapped, it's a fire risk / danger. I would get it to someone that knows how to open safely and handle a damaged Lithium Battery if it indeed has shorted itself. In the mean time, power it off and remove the charger just to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at a few of the guides at iFixit.com for the MacBook Air:
https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Air

Assuming your handy with tools and the MacBook isn't under warranty, you should be able to open it up see what's going on. Otherwise, take it to the nearest apple authorized repair facility.

You'll need a pentalobe (5 point) screwdriver to remove the bottom. Hopefully the broken bit is just a plastic tab or something that you can remove and live without. You might be able to take the bottom off and gently shake loose the broken bit causing the noise.

If that's all it is, then you should be able reassemble it and it should run normally. If you've damaged cooling fans, the battery, or any circuit boards, you'll have to identify the broken part and repair accordingly.

Good luck!